# Несколько ОС на одном компьютере

Tags: загрузка

Как сделать так, чтоб было несколько ОС на одном компьютере и при запуске компьютера можно было выбрать, какую ОС загружать?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы устанавливаете смесь Linux/Windows или Linux/Linux то все очень просто, от вас практически ничего не требуется. Просто установите вторую ОС и [grub](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRUB) сделает все за вас. [Здесь](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grub_2) руководство wiki для grub 2

Comment: Обычно лучше устанавливать сначала Windows, а затем Linux, иначе Windows затирает загрузчик Linux и процедура становится сложнее :-)